# Email notifications for search terms

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, email-notification

I would like to get email notifications for questions which match a tag, **and include a search keyword**.

I can see how to do this for tags, but not a way to filter based on keyword matches. Is this possible?

The reason why I want to do this is I am the author of a dart package called postgresql. People ask questions about it and tag the question with [dart], but forget to tag the question with [postgresql]. I would like to get an email notification for these questions so I can help my users more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to follow tags ***without*** specific search words, one through SE, and one through a third party service:

1. You can click "subscribe" on a given tag (you'll see it in a dropdown when you hover over a tag), which will send all new [tag] questions to the email you used to register your SE account.
2. You can copy the RSS feed address from the tag dropdown, and put it into a service like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), and create a recipe to send all new questions to your email.

I have done both for [tags that interest me](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slaughter-shochet-shecht) on various SE sites, even going so far as to send some new questions to my phone as a text message from my Gmail account, so that I can read the new questions without having to go online for it.

---

To get an email for every new [tag] item that matches a specific search word, you can create an IFTTT recipe that will do that for you, in under a minute. Select the "Feeds" channel, create the action "new feed item matches," enter your search term and feed (from the tag dropdown), then select the email option for the action, and you have a functional recipe!
(It sounds a lot more complicated than it really is, I promise ;-)

For your search words, you can use [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/221789-email-notification-for-postgresql-dart-questions-on-so). Enjoy!

Comment: If you need a pre-written IFTTT recipe for that, leave a comment and I'll either point one out to you that works, or I'll publish my own.

Comment: I'm aware that you can subscribe to tags. But I would like to also __filter__ the results by a __search keyword__. I've just set up an alert on google alerts for "site:stackoverflow.com dart postgresql", hopefully that will work ok.

Comment: @GregLowe You can do that through IFTTT also (make a trigger "if new feed item matches search"), but if you found something that works then all is well :-)

Comment: Cool update your question to say this and I'll mark it as accepted. i.e. Something like. SE only has and tag notifications. You must use an external service such as IFTTT.

Comment: @GregLowe How's that?